# How does \footnotesep work anyway?

Tags: footnotes, grid-typesetting

I recently developed a fascination in grid typesetting and therefore was trying to get all the elements on my page separated from each other by multiples of the `\baselineskip` value (don't try doing this, it will drive you mad). After much fiddling I got everything except the footnotes to fit. According to the LaTeX2e manual, `\footnotesep` determines the height of the struts separating the footnotes. However, having changed the fontsize of the footnotes from `\footnotesize` to `\small` and the `\baselineskip` to `14.5pt`, I can tell you that is *not* case, or at at least seems to be not the case. The strut height should be 70% of baselineskip, so `\footnotesep` should be `10.15` to guarantee that all footnotes are separated by multiples `\baselineskip`. My experience tells me though that it is far closer to `10.425pt`. So what gives? How does the algorithm actually work??

Here's my code (for lualatex):

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[textwidth=130mm,textheight=40\baselineskip, centering, a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}
\setlength{\splittopskip}{14.5pt}
\setlength{\lineskiplimit}{-\maxdimen}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{16.05pt}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{10.425pt}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\footnoterule{
    \kern-4.05\p@
    \hrule\@width.4\columnwidth
    \kern3.65\p@
}
\makeatother
\flushbottom
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{}
\renewcommand{\footnotelayout}{\small\baselineskip=14.5pt}
\newcommand{\baselinegrid}{%
    \raisebox{0pt}[\height][0pt]{\makebox[0pt][l]{%
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}%
            \begin{color}{red}%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
                \rule{\textwidth}{.05pt}\linebreak%
            \end{color}
        \end{minipage}%
}}}

\begin{document}
\baselinegrid
texttexttext\footnote{a footnote.}
\lipsum[1-2]
textextext\footnote{another footnote.}\footnote{another footnote.}\footnote{another footnote.}\footnote{another footnote.}\footnote{another footnote.}\footnote{another footnote.}\footnote{another footnote.}\footnote{another footnote.}\footnote{another footnote.}\footnote{another footnote.}
\lipsum[3-4]
\end{document}
```

This produces a document with fairly consistent line spacing in the footnotes (and throughout the whole document, for that matter). However, if you change `\footnotesep` to `10.15` you should see the separation start to happen. What is going on??

Comment: You could look at ConTeXt, which has a decent grid typesetting option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you use `\small` with a `\baselineskip` of 14.5pt. `\small` itself uses a `\baselineskip` of 13.6pt. This means that the `\strut` of `\small` has a depth of 0.3*13.6pt = 4.08pt, whereas with a `\baselineskip` of `14.5pt` that would normally be 0.3*14.5pt = 4.35pt. As setting `\baselineskip` does not alter the `\strut` you run with the `\strut` of `\small`, thus you miss 4.35-4.08=0.27pt. You have to compensate this by adding that to `\footnotesep`, which means that the correct value is 10.15+0.27=10.42pt, slightly smaller than your estimated value.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from similar code for minipage footnotes, the only use of `\footnotesep` in the standard format version of footnotes is its two occurrences in the definition of `\foonotetext` packages such as `footmisc` will have similar code, depending on options used.

```
\long\def\@footnotetext#1{\insert\footins{%
    \reset@font\footnotesize
    \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty
    \splittopskip\footnotesep
%                 %%%%%%%%%%%
    \splitmaxdepth \dp\strutbox \floatingpenalty \@MM
    \hsize\columnwidth \@parboxrestore
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{%
       \csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark
    }%
    \color@begingroup
      \@makefntext{%
        \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces#1\@finalstrut\strutbox}%
%                 %%%%%%%%%%%
    \color@endgroup}}%
```

the first use locally sets `\splittopskip` so that if a footnote is split over a page the baseline of the section carried over is `\footnotesep` from the top of the insertion box.

The second use is for the spacing at the start of each footnote where a rule with zero depth and width and height `\footnotesep` is inserted. Also at the end of each footnote a rule with zero height and width and the depth of a `\strut` is inserted.

There is no particular rule that says either `\footnotesep` or the height of a \strut should be 70% of the `\baselineskip` each of these lengths can be set interdependently.

In your case if you add `\showoutput` you will see each line of footnote text is

```
 .\hbox(10.425+4.08003)x369.88582, glue set 265.5038fil
```

So the height of the box is coming from `\footnotesep` and the depth coming from `\dp\strutbox` adding up to a little over 14.404pt so slightly more than your grid spacing. You need to set the strutbox to be of a size suitable for your baseline, and set  `\footnotesep` to `\ht\strutbox` in order to get exact spacing here. (Or at least set `\footnotesep` to `\dimexpr\baselineskip-\dp\strutbox` )